# Image name not inserted into database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I have a problem to store image name into database. image upload to folder working fine but image name will not saved into db

Model code :

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :imag
   attr_accessor :imag

  def self.save(upload)
    name = upload['imag'].original_filename
    directory = 'public/data'
    # render :text => directory
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory,name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['imag'].read)}
  end

end
```

Controller code:

```
  def create
    @a=params[:post][:imag].original_filename  /* how to pass in this image name into params[:post] */
    pos= Post.save(params[:post])
    if pos
      redirect_to :action =>"index"
    else
      redirect_to :action =>"posts"
    end
  end
```

Anyone guide me to archive this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution. Manually added image original file name in Post.create function.

Controller code :

```
 def create
            Post.super(params[:post])
            pos= Post.create(:name=>params[:post][:name],:image=>params[:post][:image].original_filename) /* here is added image value from uploaded input */
            if pos
              redirect_to :action =>"index"
            else
              redirect_to :action =>"posts"
            end

          end
```

Modle Code :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :image

  #attr_accessor :imag
  def self.super(upload)
    name = upload['image'].original_filename
    directory = 'public/data'
   # render :text => directory
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory,name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['image'].read)}
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because your save helper conflicts with the ActiveRecord save and you're not even saving doing anything in that method.

call

```
super(upload)
```

in your save method (should be the first line)

Comment: I find the solution posted below. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the ActiveRecord save method with your custom `self.save` class method.  Also, I'd recommend using an upload gem like paperclip or something similar

Comment: I have already used paperclip gem but below error will be occurred in model im using rails 4.0.0. 
Error : attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem.

Comment: That comment makes no sense.  You have overridden the default ActiveRecord save method with your own.  Your method doesnt write anything to the database.  That is why you dont have any info inserted into the DB, because you arent inserting it in your custom save method

Comment: I find the solution posted below. Thanks for your support.